# GlusterFS - Is there an easy way to count the number of files on a brick?

Tags: unix, glusterfs

I would like to count the number of files on a GlusterFS volume ending in .res. Is there a command to do this. Nothing I have found on the net is what I need. Cheers

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use command `gluster volume info volume-id` to get path of brick

[image]

Then, use command `ls -lR path_brick/*.res | wc -l`
Example in my case:

```
ls -lR /var/lib/heketi/mounts/vg_53ec29d2b03384b7f8cd5c2a609bd0f7/brick_49e5acc25f5a31438e2726b9b03feaed/brick/*res | wc -l
```